# Redimensionar tamanho da NAVBAR quando rolar a pagina

Tags: css, bootstrap-3, nav-bar

estou tentando fazer a Navbar diminuir quando dou scroll na pagina, atribuindo a classe `.sticky` na `<nav>`. Mas por algum motivo, a barra não diminui, apenas muda de cor. Já tentei atribuir a classe em outra `<div>`, mas o tamanho não muda, apenas a cor.

Estou usando Bootstrap.

Confira no codepen: https://codepen.io/Caladan/pen/rwmjBb

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz três pequenas alterações no seu codepen, e me pareceu funcionar como você quer:

1- A height a Navbar é criada na classe ".navbar" e não na ".nagivation".

```
.navbar {

height: 100px;

  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
   transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

2- Criei a classe ".sticky" separada (você pode criar ela em conjunto com as outras depois, mas acho melhor ter ela sozinho primeiro).

```
.sticky{
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  visibility: visible;
  height: 40px !important;
}
```

3-No Js file selecionei a classe ".navbar", que é onde a classe ".sticky" será inserida

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('sticky');
  }
});
```

obs: Eu alterei as cores das barras .sticky e .navbar, para ter uma melhor percepção do que se estava a passar.

Answer (score 0):

Isto está ocorrendo porque o seu elemento .navigation está bloqueando a altura do conteudo, experimente acrecentar este css:

```
.sticky .navigation {
    min-height:80px;
    height:80px;
}
```

você precisa tratar os elementos filhos para que sua barra fique correta.